# getDeclaredMethod in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, methods

I have a question about "getDeclaredMethod" in kotlin.

I have a class:

```
class WorksheetFreeField : Serializable {

@SerializedName("val_value_1")
var val_value_1: String? = ""
@SerializedName("val_value_2")
var val_value_2: String? = ""
@SerializedName("val_value_3")
var val_value_3: String? = ""
```

Now I try this:

```
try {
            val c = WorksheetFreeField::class
            for (field in fields) {
                val method = c.java.getDeclaredMethod("setVal_value_" + field.order)
```

Now I got this error in my catch:

```
com.werkbon.objects.WorksheetFreeField.setVal_value_1 []
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `c.java.declaredMethods` in debug mode. Method `setVal_value_1` exists, but has a parameter of type `String`.

So to make `c.java.getDeclaredMethod` work,  you have to call it with 2  parameters: method name and `String::class.java`.